# Linear Programming Convexity Proof

Tags: proof-writing, linear-programming

Suppose a linear programming problem in standard form has as constraints $A \underline{X} = b$ and $\underline{X} \geq \underline{0}$,
where $\underline{A}$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $\underline{b}$; $\underline{c}$; and $\underline{0}$ are column vectors of the appropriate size. I seek to prove that
the feasible set is convex in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I am able also to freely utilize the properties of matrix algebra in my proof.

How would I prove this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the $\underline{c}$ come in?

Comment: I believe $\underline{c}$ is the column vector representing the coefficients of the obj fcn.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is easier not to think about matrices but about the linear functions represented by them.

The preimage of a convex set, such as $\{b\}$, under a linear function is easily be shown to beconvex and the intersection of convex sets is convex.